# I can't get tkSimpleDialog to work in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following python test program. When I run it I expect to be able to click on the "Dialog" menu and select "Show Dialog" and have the dialog box pop up. Instead I get:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "testdialogs.py", line 13, in dialog_show
    result = tkSimpleDialog.askstring('Result', 'Where to next?')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'askstring'
```

As you can tell this is on a Mac running python 2.7.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkSimpleDialog

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, 
            width=1000, 
            height=500)

canvas.pack()

def dialog_show():
    result = tkSimpleDialog.askstring('Result', 'Where to next?')

menu = tk.Menu(root)

dialog_menu = tk.Menu(menu)

dialog_menu.add_command(label="Show Dialog", command=dialog_show)
menu.add_cascade(label="Dialog",menu=dialog_menu)

root.config(menu=menu)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can't reproduce this error on Mac with Python 2.7.3, although copy/pasting your code didn't work for another reason

Comment: works for me on  python 2.6.2 under windows vista.

Comment: Could it be possible that you have a file named `tkSimpleDialog.py` in your current directory ?

Comment: Thanks to all. It turns out there was a spurious .pyc file in the directory. Problem solved.